# Bash Script skipping loop iterations when executing other scripts

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that runs another script with different arguments. These arguments are taken from the first column of a csv file. Here's the code:

```
code_sections_file="code_sections.csv"
script="testing.sh"
pwd
awk -F "," '{print $1}' "$code_sections_file" | while IFS= read -r element; do
    echo "======= $element ========"
    ./testing.sh "$element"
done
```

However, some of these iterations do not seem to be executed. When I just print the element inside the loop without executing "testing.sh" it prints every element.

However, when I execute the testing.sh, the same print (`echo "======= $element ========"`) is not printed, so I'm guessing that the problem is related to how I am running "testing.sh".

The testing.sh script changes some lines in several files and then runs a tool in those files. The output of that tool is saved in several log files. Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

file_non_compile=()

#============================== CSV Structure ====================================
# Bug Name, Example Name, Example Path, Starting Line, Ending Line
#=================================================================================

code_sections_file="code_sections.csv"

# ---------------------------- Preprocessing input -------------------------------
result="$1"
result_line=$(grep "^$result," "$code_sections_file")
IFS="," read -ra info_array <<< $result_line

bug="${info_array[0]}"
example_name="${info_array[1]}"
example_path="${info_array[2]}"
first_line="${info_array[3]}"
second_line="${info_array[4]}" 

# ------------------------------ Directory Paths ----------------------------------
error_path="../testlogs/noncompiled/$bug"
code_folder="nvml/src/examples/libpmemobj/$example_path"   # nvml/src/examples/libpmemobj/$example_path - Path to the file
original_folder="../original/$example_path"                # ../original/$example_path - Path to the original state of the file
buged_folder="../buged/$example_path"                      # ../buged/$example_path - Path to the bugged state of the file
patch_path="./patch/$example_name/$bug.patch"              # ./patch/$example_path{-.c+patch} - file with the buggy patch
IFS='/'
read -ra patharr <<< "$example_path"
testlogs_path="../testlogs/${patharr[0]}/$bug"             # ../testlogs/$example_path.split("/")[0]/$bug_(prompt_eng_tech).txt - file with logs
results="../masterThesis/Results"                         # ../masterThesis/Results/{prompt}/{$bug.txt} 

echo "$patch_path"
echo "$bug $example_name $example_path $first_line $second_line"

# ==================================================================================

# Copy original code file to a folder
cp $code_folder $original_folder
sleep 10

# ===================================== Bug ========================================

echo "=========== $bug ============="
sleep 5


# Apply the patch bug
echo "Applying the bug patch..."
./patch/patch.sh ./ $patch_path
sleep 2

# Copy buggy file to a folder
cp $code_folder $buged_folder
echo "Done."
sleep 10

# Build the examples
echo "Compiling the code..."
make nvml-example &> /dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo " ========== Make failed =============== "
    file_non_compile+=(" ")
    read
fi
echo "Done."
sleep 4

# Execute program and save log to file.
echo "Executing the buggy program..."
sudo make nvml-exec arg=$example_name > ../testlogs/$example_name/$bug.txt
echo "Done. Output saved to ../testlogs/$example_name/$bug.txt"
sleep 2

# ======================================================================================

verify_correction() {
    current_strategy=$1
    echo $current_strategy
    echo "Writing bug correction..."
    prev_line=$((first_line - 1))
    sed "${first_line},${second_line}d" $code_folder > ../temp.txt && sed -n -e "/\`\`\` \?C/,/\`\`\`/p" -e "/''' \?C/,/'''/p" $results/$current_strategy/$bug.txt | sed '1d;$d' | sed "${prev_line}r /dev/stdin" ../temp.txt > ../temp2.txt && mv ../temp2.txt ../temp.txt

    #sed '180,239d' nvml/src/examples/libpmemobj/hashmap/hashmap_tx.c > ../temp.txt && sed '4,57!d' ../mastersThesis/Results/ZeroShot/hashmap_tx_backup_3.txt | sed '179r /dev/stdin' ../temp.txt > ../temp2.txt && mv ../temp2.txt ../temp.txt
    # Write temp file content to original file
    cp ../temp.txt $code_folder
    echo "Done."

    # Rebuild Examples
    echo "Compiling code..."
    make nvml-example &> /dev/null
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo " ========== Make failed =============== "
        file_non_compile+=("$bug\_$1")
        read
    fi
    echo "Done."
    sleep 4

    # Execute "repaired" program and save to logs
    echo "Executing program with Zero-Shot correction..."
    sudo make nvml-exec arg=$example_name > ../testlogs/$example_name/$bug\_$2.txt
    echo "Done. Output saved to ../testlogs/$example_name/$bug\_$2.txt"

    # Return buggy code
    echo "Reverting to buggy code and recompiling..."
    cp ../buged/$example_path $code_folder
    make nvml-example &> /dev/null
    echo "Done."
    sleep 2
}

# ================================= Zero-Shot Learning =================================

verify_correction "ZeroShot" "Zero"
verify_correction "ZeroShotCoT" "ZeroCoT"
verify_correction "MoreExamples/FewShot" "Two"
verify_correction "MoreExamples/FewShotCoT" "TwoCoT"
verify_correction "OneExample/FewShot" "One"
verify_correction "OneExample/FewShotCoT" "OneCoT"

echo "Reset code sample..."
./patch/patch.sh -R ./ $patch_path
sleep 2
echo "Done."

echo "The following corrections did not compile:"
if [ ${#file_non_compile[@]} -gt 0 ]; then
    for file in "${file_non_compile[@]}"; do
        echo "$file" >> "$error_path"
    done
fi

echo "All verifications done for bug $bug."
echo "Results can be found in ../testlogs/$example_name/ folder."
```

Comment: please update the question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and more detailed explanation of the behavior (expected vs actual); at this point we're left guessing what `testing.sh` does and what the output looks like, eg, are you saying some of the `echo` outputs are not being presented on stdout when `testing.sh` is called? or do all of the `echo` outputs show up on stdout but you're not sure if `testing.sh` is being called? if the latter then it sounds like you may need to debug `testing.sh`.

Comment: Your script has several quoting errors etc. Probably run it through https://shellcheck.net/ and fix what it finds. Asking us to debug all of it isn't really realistic. But try running it with `</dev/null` in the calling script to prevent it from consuming standard input.

Comment: there's nothing *minimal* about a 135-line script; this 135-line script is not *reproducible* by us in our own envs (eg, what is `patch.sh`, we can't run the `make` calls, etc); there's no indication of how you're determining this script is not being called on all passes through your main loop; there are a ton of `echo` (debug(ish)) calls in the script which raises the question ... have you perused the tons of output to see if the code is flowing as designed?

Comment: `testing.sh` is almost certainly reading stdin and so consuming some of the piped `awk` output. Create and post a [mcve] (after fixing any issues that shellcheck tells you about) so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the script from `awk`

```
awk -F "," '{system("./testing.sh " $1)}' "$code_sections_file"
```

This replaces the entire pipeline to the `while read` loop.